# Подключение файлов перевода темы .po .mo - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

У меня тема на английском, но есть файлы перевода **.po** и **.mo** на русский.
Делаю как говорится в рекомендации - в файле **wp-config.php** прописываю
    **define( 'WPLANG', 'ru_RU' );**
Но ни че не помогает. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что у вас получилось прописать define( 'WPLANG', 'ru_RU' ); у вас не русифицированная версия вордпресса. 
Скачайте с [сайта](https://ru.wordpress.org/) русскую версию и поставьте плагин локализации [Loco Translate](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)

Comment: Русская версия стоит

Comment: В русской версии уже прописан define( 'WPLANG', 'ru_RU' ), а что с плагином перевода?

Answer (score 1):

Файлы перевода должны находиться в папке mysite.com/wp-content/themes/my_theme/languages

В большинстве случаев будет работать.

Иногда разработчики темы забывают подключить текстовый домен. Тогда в functions.php надо добавить следующий код

```
function my_theme_setup {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'my_theme' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup' );
```

где my_theme - имя вашей темы.